# Pandas filtering based on OR AND

Tags: pandas

I am trying to filter rows in a pandas df like this:

```
df1= df0[(df0.col1=='a' ) | (df0.col2=='b' & df0.col3=='c')]
```

I believe i used proper parentheses, but I get:

```
cannot compare a dtyped [object] array with a scalar of type [bool]
```

Basically, if a OR (b&C) is true is the condition i want

Comment: `df0[(df0.col1=='a' ) | ((df0.col2=='b') & (df0.col3=='c'))]`

Comment: Your parentheses arrange is leading to an evaluation of `'b' & df.col3`, which I think is generating your error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing)

> Another common operation is the use of boolean vectors to filter the
>   data. The operators are: | for or, & for and, and ~ for not. These
>   **must be grouped by using parentheses**, since by default Python will
>   evaluate an expression such as df.A > 2 & df.B < 3 as df.A > (2 &
>   df.B) < 3, while the desired evaluation order is (df.A > 2) & (df.B <
>   3).

```
df1 = df0[(df0.col1=='a' ) | ((df0.col2=='b') & (df0.col3=='c'))]
```

Comment: This useful answer has very few approvals!